# Logic to test whether Linux environment modules are needed

Tags: r, slurm, environment-modules

I help maintain an R package that auto-generates shell scripts for using Slurm to run `Rscript` on a remote server. There is a template for a `submit.sh` script that is filled in with arguments supplied by the user in an R function. However some systems are configured with environment modules so that the shell script needs to have the line `module load R` before `Rscript` is called.

**Is there some logic I can execute from within R to detect whether `module load R` is necessary so that the line `module load R` is included in the shell script, conditional on whether or not it's necessary?**

Link to the source code of our R package: [rslurm](https://github.com/SESYNC-ci/rslurm)
Template for `submit.sh`: [submit.sh.txt](https://github.com/SESYNC-ci/rslurm/blob/master/inst/templates/submit_sh.txt)

Comment: You can check out the module documentation: https://modules.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html. You can use things like `module list` to see all currently loaded modules or `module is-loaded R` to see if the module is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the shell script, you may check if the `module` shell function is defined, then check if the `R` module exists in which case an attempt to load this module should be made:

```
type module >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ] && module is-avail R; then
    module load R
fi
```

If the `R` module is already loaded, the `module load` command will do nothing. So it is safe to use it even if `R` module is already loaded.